Maximum and concavity of function
I have a function
\begin{align}
G(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta_1d\theta_2d\theta_3}{(2\pi)^3} p(\vec{x},\vec{\theta}) \log\left( p(\vec{x}, \vec{\theta})\right)
\end{align}
defined on the probability simplex $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^3 x_i =1$ and $x_i \geq 0$, where
\begin{align}
p(\vec{x},\vec{\theta}) = \left( \sum_{i,j=1}^3 \sqrt{x_i x_j} e^{i (\theta_i-\theta_j)}\right) = 1 +  2  \sum_{i \leq j} \sqrt{x_i x_j} \cos(\theta_i- \theta_j) 
\end{align}
One can see that $p(\vec{x},\vec{\theta}) \geq 0$ (point wise i.e. for any $\vec{x}, \vec{\theta}$ in the domain) and that $G$ is non-negative ($G \geq 0$).
I'd like to understand where its maximum is and if there is a simple closed-form expression for the maximum value.
It can be seen numerically that $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 1/3$  is the unique maximum point which yields $G_{max} \approx 0.329524$. One way to do so would be to show $G$ is strictly concave, which I also see to be numerically true. But I am not sure how to show that analytically. Any help/advice would be much appreciated, thanks.

denoting $y_i=\sqrt{x_1}$ and $f(y,\theta)=\sum_j y_je^{i\theta_j}$ then $p=f\overline{f}=|f|^2$ and $$p\log p=\frac{d}{ds}|f|^{2s}|_{s=1}.$$ Maybe proving concavity of  $x\mapsto |f|^{2s}$ is not impossible.

@LetacGérard I don't think this can work; the issue is that $x \mapsto | f |^{2s}$ for fixed $\theta$ isn't necessarily concave (you can numerically see some $\theta$ where this becomes convex), but upon integration $x \mapsto \int |f |^{2s}$ (averaging over all $\theta$) the average function should become strictly concave (this is the desired statement).
